# Host Website or App for Limit Hold ‘em Tournaments

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, online, live

Looking to find an app or website where I can host a poker tournament that is limit hold em. I’d like to have the ability to raise the limit every 30 min.

For context, we have a time limit poker tournament every year and we use a service called  The Tournament Director. This service allows you to input the time limit of the tournament and it will automatically tell you when to raise the blinds based on the amount of people so it ends on time. Looking to mimic this as close as possible through a poker app since we are doing it virtually this year.

There is an app called pokerrr but this only offers pot limit or no limit in a tournament style and wondering if there is another option that can meet my needs.

Has anyone used another service that offers this?

Comment: It has been a long time since I have hosted a tournament online. But look around at the online poker sites, lots of them used to host private tournaments, but I do not know whom if anyone does now. (Thus a comment instead of an answer)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Yeah the only thing I can find currently is pokerrr but it does not have limit holdem only pot limit

Comment: And you've looked at the PokerStars options? They have a very robust "private" invite-only game mechanism. I don't recall if they have limit - but I believe they do.

Answer (score 2):

you can email most online poker sites and get them to set up a restricted game with your desired blinds/structure, and I believe PokerStars and PartyPoker (GVC) both let you create you own games via the client.